# Finding maximum value of perimeter of trapezium using tan θ

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I study maths as a hobby. I am struggling with this problem.

In a trapezium ABCD the sides AB, DC are parallel and $\angle ABC$ is a right angle. If AD = DB = 10 cm and $\angle DAB = \theta$ find the value of $\tan \theta$ for which the perimeter p cm is a maximum. Hence find the range of values taken by p for $0\lt\theta\lt\frac{1}{2}\pi$

My working is as follows:

$\tan \theta = \frac{DE}{EA} = \frac{CB}{EA}$

$CB = EA.\tan \theta$

$EA = 10 \cos \theta \to CB = 10 \cos \theta \tan \theta$

$ABD$ is isosceles so $BE = EA$

$CD = EA = 10 \cos \theta$

$BA = 20 \cos \theta$

So perimeter P = $20 \cos \theta + 10 \cos \theta \tan \theta + 10 \cos \theta + 10$

$= 30 \cos \theta + 10 cos \theta \tan \theta + 10$

$\frac{dP}{d\theta} = - 30 \sin \theta + 10 \cos \theta \sec^2 \theta - 10 \sin \theta \tan \theta$

But now I am stuck.

[image: This is the diagram I have drawn]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P=30\cos\theta+10\sin\theta+10 \\ P’ = -30\sin\theta+10\cos\theta = 0 \implies \tan\theta =\frac 13$$ You may use $$\sin\theta= \frac{\tan\theta}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}} \\ \cos\theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}} $$

Answer (score 0):

Once you have expressed the perimeter as
$$P(\theta) = 30\cos \theta + 10\sin \theta + 10,$$
you can even avoid calculus by just rewriting $P$ as
\begin{eqnarray}P&=&10 \left[3\cos\theta + \sin \theta + 1\right]=\\
&=&10 \left[\sqrt{10}\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} \cos\theta + \frac1{\sqrt{10}}\sin\theta\right)+1\right]=\\
&=&10\left[\sqrt{10}\sin\left(\theta +\arctan 3 \right)+1\right],
\end{eqnarray}
which reaches its maximum when the argument of $\sin$ is $\frac{\pi}2$, yielding
$$\theta_{max} = \frac{\pi}2 - \arctan 3= \arctan \frac13$$